# Complex exponent.

Tags: complex-analysis

In every complex analysis book it is proved that $z^{a}z^{b}=z^{a+b}(a,b\in\mathbb{C})$ and proof is like below $$z^{a}z^{b}=e^{a~ln(z)}e^{b~ln(z)}=e^{aln(z)+bln(z)}=e^{(a+b)ln}=z^{a+b}.$$ 
Now my doubt is how can we write $a~ln(z)+b~ln(z)=(a+b)ln(z)$? As there are sets on both side of the equality and in  set theory it is not true that if $A$ is a  non empty set then $aA+bA=(a+b)A.$ Then how can we say here that $a~ln(z)+b~ln(z)=(a+b)ln(z)$? One more example is $ln(i.i)=ln(i)+ln(i)\neq 2ln(i).$ Where i am getting problem? Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any "sets on both sides"; I see values of complex functions.

Comment: its infinite values function

Comment: $ln(z)=ln(|z|)+i(Arg(z)+2n\pi)$

Comment: ln(z) is infinite valued so both sides are infinite sets....

Comment: No, you pick a branch in order to make $\ln(z)$ single-valued. Check your complex analysis books!

Comment: no no in books its true for general ln(z) function...

Comment: its true for general exponent....

Comment: It is true for any $\ln(z)$ function created by picking a branch to make it single-valued. Case closed.

Comment: it is not mention that we are taking any branch...

Comment: "It" being which book? Cite your sources.

Comment: zill complex analysis page no 196...

Comment: complex analysis by A.David Wunsch....page no 132 exercise 13...

Comment: I just reviewed the Zill section - it is wrong to say that $z^az^b=z^{a+b}$ for multivalued functions, for exactly the reason you found out. It is only true if one chooses a branch for $\ln$. I didn't look at the Wunsch one.

Comment: ok then is it wrongly written there?

Comment: in churchill it is written for principal branch as you told...